# Is there an R function to add a common 'word' to all row under a particular column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this dataset below

```
Country   Sales
France    12000
Germany   2400
Italy     1000
Belgium   500
```

Please can you help with a code to add a common 'word' to the Country. I have tried all my best. Here is the intended output I want. thanks

```
Country            Sales
France - Europe    12000
Germany - Europe   2400
Italy - Europe     1000
Belgium - Europe   500
```

Thanks, as you help me

Comment: `dat$Country <- paste0(dat$Country, "- Europe")`?

Comment: Based on this and your previous question, though I wonder if you should be doing this: I'm inferring that your data might include data from other countries not necessarily in Europe, in which case you would need this to be done conditionally based on the (original) value of `Country`. If that's the case ... you may need to alter your data wrangling _a little_.

Answer (score 0):

```r
country_data <-
  data.frame(
    country = c(
      "France",
      "Germany",
      "Italy",
      "Belgium"
    ),
    sales = c(
      12000,
      2400,
      1000,
      500
    )
  )

country_data_2 <-
  country_data |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    continent = dplyr::case_when(
      country %in% c("France", "Germany", "Italy", "Belgium") ~ "Europe",
      country %in% c("Egypt", "South Africa", "Morroco") ~ "Africa",
      country %in% c("Canada", "Mexico", "United States") ~ "North America"
      # ...
    )
  ) |>
  dplyr::transmute(
    country = paste(
      country,
      continent,
      sep = " - "
    ),
    sales = sales
  )

country_data_2
#>            country sales
#> 1  France - Europe 12000
#> 2 Germany - Europe  2400
#> 3   Italy - Europe  1000
#> 4 Belgium - Europe   500
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).